# Get IWorkSpace from IGxObject

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcobjects, arcmap

I am creating a tool that opens an `IGxDialog` which it's objects are filtered to show only workspaces, my question is how can I convert `IGxObject` to `IWorkSpace` or get the selected workspace without taking the selected object name and opening it using an `IWorkSpaceFactory`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works for geodatabases, but I haven't figured out how to get a workspace for a shapefile using this method

```
Private Sub GetWorkspace()

    Dim pEnumGxObj As ESRI.ArcGIS.Catalog.IEnumGxObject
    Dim pFCFilter As New ESRI.ArcGIS.Catalog.GxFilterWorkspaces
    Dim pGxDatabase As ESRI.ArcGIS.Catalog.IGxDatabase2
    Dim pGxDialog As New ESRI.ArcGIS.CatalogUI.GxDialog
    Dim pGxObject As ESRI.ArcGIS.Catalog.IGxObject
    Dim pWorkspace As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IWorkspace

    pGxDialog.ObjectFilter = pFCFilter

    If Not pGxDialog.DoModalOpen(My.ArcMap.Application.hWnd, pEnumGxObj) Then Exit Sub

    pGxObject = pEnumGxObj.Next

    If pGxObject Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Try
        If TypeOf pGxObject Is ESRI.ArcGIS.Catalog.IGxDatabase2 Then
            pGxDatabase = pGxObject
            pWorkspace = pGxDatabase.Workspace
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(pWorkspace.PathName)
        Else
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("This is likely a shapefile workspace")
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString, "GetWorkspace")

    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this (WILL ONLY WORK WHEN IGXOBJECT IS A SHAPEFILE):

```
                ESRI.ArcGIS.Catalog.IGxDataset gxDataset; //Declare IgxDataset
                gxDataset = (IGxDataset)gxObj; //cast IgxObject to IgxDataset
                ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IDataset gDataset;//Declare IDataset
                gDataset = gxDataset.Dataset; //IGxDataset to IDataset
                ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IWorkspace gxWorkspace; //Declare workspace
                gxWorkspace = gDataset.Workspace; //IDataset to IWorkspace
```

The order is IGxObject > IGxDataset > IDataset > IWorkspace.

Comment: When setting the IGxDialog filter to show only workspaces, you'll get an error when trying to cast the IGxObject as an IGxDataset.

Comment: Yes. However, the above code will properly provide the workspace when IGxObject is a shapefile. I have edited my answer accordingly. Perhaps a combination of our two implementations may best suit the original poster.

Comment: I tried this thing before, and it gives me an InvalidCastException when trying to cast the IGxObject (which I've selected a workspace) to IGxDataset

Answer (score 2):

This one works for me. It is tested for file geodatabase, personal geodatabase.

```
//enumGxObject = output of IGxDialogue
IWorkspace GetWorkspace(IEnumGxObject enumGxObject)
{
    IGxObject gxObject;
    while ((gxObject = enumGxObject.Next()) != null)
    {
        Catalog.IGxDatabase2 gxDatabase;
        if ((gxDatabase = gxObject as IGxDatabase2) != null)
           return gxDatabase.Workspace;
        if(IsShapeFileWorkspace(gxObject))
           return GetShapeFileWorkspace(gxObject);
    }
    return null;
}
```

**Edit:** added code will check shape file workspace and will return shape file workspace.

```
bool IsShapeFileWorkspace(IGxObject gxObject)
{
    if((gxObject as GxShapefileDataset) == null)
        return false;
    return true;
}

IWorkspace GetShapeFileWorkspace(IGxObject gxObject)
{
    var gxFolder = gxObject as Catalog.IGxFolder;
    var iName = FileSystemWorkspaceNames.Next();
    return iName.Open() as IWorkspace;
}
```

I hope it will work for u too.